# TSQL union all - error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following query to pull some information from 2 tables to populate a drop-down field on my website with "Category" values.

I'm getting the following error.

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

This is my query:

```
select 'Choose a Category', 'All'

Union All

select distinct CategoryName 
from BND_Listing
inner join BND_listingCategories on BND_Listing.CatID = BND_ListingCategories.CatID
```

I suspect it has something to do with the inner join?

Any input appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to union a query that returns 2 columns (`'Choose a Category','All'`) with another one than only returns one (`CategoryName`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'Choose a Category' as CategoryName
Union All
select 'All' as CategoryName
Union All
select distinct CategoryName from BND_Listing
inner join BND_listingCategories
on BND_Listing.CatID=BND_ListingCategories.CatID
```

or

```
select 'Choose a Category' as CategoryName, 'All' as Value
Union All
select distinct CategoryName, CategoryName as Value from BND_Listing
inner join BND_listingCategories
on BND_Listing.CatID=BND_ListingCategories.CatID
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Markus!

Comment: What if i want the text displayed as "Choose a Category" but the value "All"?

Comment: Then you also have to add a value to the select below. All queries combined with `Union All` must have the same number of columns, and data types.